# How to open links in UIWebView in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I want to open a link in my application and I don't want to close my application aw well. I have navigation bar on top of application and just below the navigation I want to open my web view. I have defined my outlet.

```
 IBOutlet  UIWebView *displaySingleData;
```

How will I open an link in my application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 1):

jst write following code :

```
[displaySingleData loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
```

Happy coding..